# Sending JavaScript array to Php with ajax not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to send the content of a JavaScript array to a different page using `$.post`, but it doesn't work - the corresponding `$_POST` is not set...

Can someone explain me what's wrong ?

Here is the Javascript code, on page 1:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = sessionStorage.length;
    var categoriesTab = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem(sessionStorage.key(j)) == 'active') {
            categoriesTab.push(sessionStorage.key(j));
        }
    }
    const liste = document.getElementById('liste');
    liste.addEventListener('click', function (event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if (window.location.href == 'https://dom.fr/page1/'){
            $.post(
                'page2.php',
                {
                    categoriesActives : categoriesTab
                }
            )
        }
        window.location.assign('https://dom.fr/page2/');
    });
</script>
```

The `categoriesTab` variable is set and everything seems to work.
But when I get to page 2, `$_POST` is empty... :

```
<?php

$array = [];

if (isset($_POST['categoriesActives'])) {
    $array = $_POST['categoriesActives'];
} else {
    $array = ['a', 'z', 'e', 'r'];
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `categoriesTab` contains any entities before making the request?

Comment: yes, I made a console.log and it's good

Comment: What error are you seeing? Do you see the call going in the network tab?

Comment: there's no error, neither in the console nor in the php log, and I don't see the call going in the network tab

Answer (score 1):

You are making two requests:

1. `$.post('page2.php', ...` sends an AJAX POST request to `page2.php` with the POST data you specified. You can see that request by checking the Network Tab in your Browsers Developer Tools.
2. `window.location.assign('https://dom.fr/page2/');` redirects the browser to the specified URL using a normal GET request. In that case $_POST is empty because it is another request.

Comment: ok thanks! for 1. I see it and it functions correctly; but how do I redirect the user to page 2 without making a second request?

Comment: why are you making an ajax request if all you want is to have the user see the second page? why not send a normal post request?

Answer (score 0):

You can save your array at the page2.php

```
$_SESSION['my-array'] = $_POST['categoriesActives'];
```

Next redirect user like you do, but to the page3.php

```
window.location.assign('https://dom.fr/page3/');
```

And at the page3.php you get this array:

```
 $array = [];

 if (isset($_SESSION['my-array'])) {
    $array = $_SESSION['my-array'];
    unset($_SESSION['my-array']);
 } else {
    $array = ['a', 'z', 'e', 'r'];
 }
```